# Can't insert data from registration page (php) to mysql

Tags: php, mysql

Having trouble inserting data from .php file to mysql. Don't know what the problem is. I have two main .php files. The first is the homepage:

```
   <!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Frameset//EN"     "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/frameset.dtd">
    <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en" id="jmtoday" class="   no_js">
    <html>
    <head>
    <link href='icon.jpg' rel='icon' type='image/jpg'/>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="Content-language" content="en" />
    <LINK REL=StyleSheet HREF="Mainstyles.css" TYPE="text/css"></link>
    <Title>Welcome to JM Today</title>
    </head>
    <body>
    <div class="container">
    <div class="header"><a class="logo" HREF="Homepage.html"><img src="Logo.png" alt="[JM   Today]" ></a></div>
    <div class="navbar">
   <ul class="navbar"><li class="navbar"><a class="navbar" HREF="Homepage.html">Homepage</a>   </li>
    <li class="navbar"><a class="navbar" HREF="Classes.html">Classes</a></li>
    <li class="navbar"><a class="navbar" HREF="Calendar.html">Calendar</a></li>
    <li class="navbar"><a href="Tutoring.html" class="navbar">Tutoring</a></li>
    <li class="navbar"><a href="News.html" class="navbar" >News</a></li>
    <li class="navbar"><a href="Aboutus.html" class="navbar">About Us</a></li></div>
    <div class="left"></div>
    <div class="content"><h2 class="homepage">For Students. By Students.</h2><p>Welcome to     JM Today, where you could find anything about your school, your classmates, and everything else. Online.<br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/></p></div>
<div class="signup"><h2 class="homepage">Sign Up Now</h2><h3 class="homepage">It's free, as you expected.</h3>
    <form name="registration_form" method="post" action="register.php" onsubmit="return  Validate();"><input type=hidden name=todo value=post>
    <table>
 <tr><td class="label">First Name:</td><td><input type="text" name="fname"></td></tr>
 <tr><td class="label">Last Name:</td><td><input type="text" name="lname"></td></tr>
 <tr><td class="label">E-Mail Address:</td><td><input type="text" name="email"></td>   </tr>
 <tr><td class="label">Username:</td><td><input type="text" name="username"></td></tr>
 <tr><td class="label">Password:</td><td><input type="password" name="password"></td></tr>
 <tr><td class="label">Password Confirmation:</td><td><input type="password"   name="password_confirmation"></td></tr>
 <tr><td class="label"><input type="submit" value="Register"></td></tr>
 </form>
 </table>
 <script language = "Javascript">

    function Validate()
    {
        if (document.registration_form.fname.value == '') 
        {
            alert('Please fill in your  first name!');
            return false;
        }
        if (document.registration_form.lname.value == '') 
        {
            alert('Please fill in your last name!');
            return false;
        }
        if (document.registration_form.email.value == '') 
        {
           alert('Please fill in your email address!');
           return false;
        }
        if (document.registration_form.username.value == '') 
        {
            alert('Please fill in your desired username!');
            return false;
        }
        if (document.registration_form.password.value == '') 
        {
           alert('Please fill in your desired password!');
          return false;
        }
        if (document.registration_form.password_confirmation.value == '') 
        {
           alert('Please fill in your password again for confirmation!');
          return false;
        }
        if (document.registration_form.password.value != 
        document.registration_form.password_confirmation.value) 
        {
            alert("The two passwords are not identical! "+
            "Please enter the same password again for confirmation");
            return false;
        }

        return true;
    }
    </script>

    </div>
    </div>

    <div class="footer"><p class="copyright">JMToday &copy; 2010</p><p class="right">A Samir    Ghobril Production</p></div>
    </body>
```

And the second is register.php

```
    !DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Frameset//EN"    "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/frameset.dtd">
    <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en" id="jmtoday" class="    no_js">
    <html>
    <head>
    <link href='icon.jpg' rel='icon' type='image/jpg'/>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="Content-language" content="en" />
    <LINK REL=StyleSheet HREF="Mainstyles.css" TYPE="text/css"></link>
    <Title>Sign up to JM Today</title>
    </head>
    <body>
    <?php 
    $dbservertype='mysql';
    $servername='localhost';
    $dbusername='root';
    $dbpassword='****';
    $dbname='jmtdy';
    connecttodb($servername,$dbname,$dbusername,$dbpassword);
    function connecttodb($servername,$dbname,$dbuser,$dbpassword)
    {
    global $link;
    $link=mysql_connect ("$servername","$dbuser","$dbpassword");
    if(!$link){die("Could not connect to MySQL");}
    mysql_select_db("$dbname",$link) or die ("could not open db".mysql_error());
    }
    ?>

    <?php

    $username=$_POST['username'];
    $password=$_POST['password'];
    $password2=$_POST['password_confirmation'];
    $todo=$_POST['todo'];
    $email=$_POST['email'];
    $fname=$_POST['fname'];
    $lname=$_POST['lname'];



    if(isset($todo) and $todo=="post"){

    $status = "OK";
    $msg="";


if(!isset($username) OR strlen($userid) <3){
$msg=$msg."Username should be equal to or more than 3 characters long<BR/>";
$status= "NOTOK";}     

    if(mysql_num_rows(mysql_query("SELECT username FROM users WHERE username =    '$username'"))){
    $msg=$msg."Username already exists. Please try another one<BR/>";
    $status= "NOTOK";}     


    if ( strlen($password) < 3 ){
    $msg=$msg."Password must be more than 3 charactors long<BR/>";
    $status= "NOTOK";}     

    if ( $password <> $password2 ){
    $msg=$msg."Passwords are not identical.<BR/>";
    $status= "NOTOK";}     


    if($status<>"OK"){
    echo "$msg<br/><input type='button' value='Retry' onClick='history.go(-1)'>";
    }else{
    if(mysql_query("insert into users(username,password,email,fname,lname)      values('$username','$password','$email','$fname','$lname')")){
    echo "Welcome, You have successfully signed up";}
    else{ echo "Database Problem, please contact Site admin";

    }

    }
    }
    ?>
    </body>
    </html>
```

If you could please help me i would greatly appreciate it.
[edit]ok, i fixed up the code and got this error message. Access denied for user 'www-data'@'localhost' (using password: NO). Does this help?

Comment: What happens? What doesn't work?

Comment: YOU DON'T REALLY use **root** as login and don't do any escaping of input, whatsoever, do you?

Comment: do you get any errors? does anything get printed`? you should write after each mysql_query() or die (mysql_error ()) to make it print any occured mysql errors

Comment: http://validator.w3.org/ — why on earth do you have a Frameset Doctype?

Comment: All I get is a blank page and when I check mysql no data is added.

Answer (score 2):

It might have helped if you would have posted the response.

On my test I got this

```
Username should be equal to or more than 3 characters long
```

although I used one with 6 characters. Looking at the code it's obvious:

```
$username=$_POST['username'];

[...]

if(!isset($username) OR strlen($userid) <3){
    $msg=$msg."Username should be equal to or more than 3 characters long<BR/>";
    $status= "NOTOK";
}
```

You simply used the wrong variable $userid instead of $username. Correct it and the script should be working.

But before you do so, there a a few more things wrong with your code:

1. Never use PHP variables directly in SQL! Encapsulate them with [mysql_real_escape_string](http://de3.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-real-escape-string.php) or better use something like [mysqli_prepare()](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.prepare.php) or your script will be open for a SQL-injection attacks and a lot of trouble with characters like "'"
2. Never use root as database user for your scripts. Create one with fewer rights to minimize the effect if there is some hole in your SQL handling.
3. Clean up your code! Indention are there for a reason and help you read yours (and others) code. At least do it before posting it and asking for help. With a bit of luck you would have found the error by yourself.
4. Check your HTML. There are a lot of invalid things in there...

Comment: I tried that and it still didn't work. I'm still getting a blank page.

Comment: Try adding <?php error_reporting(E_ALL); ?> at the top of register.php

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing one of the queries is dying because you haven't properly escaped any of the data you're inserting into the queries. Consider what happens when someone fills in username like this:

```
$username = "Miles O'Brien"
$query = "SELECT username FROM users WHERE username =    '$username'";
```

$query then becomes:

```
SELECT username FROM users WHERE username = 'Miles O'Brien'
                                                     ^^^^^^-- "bad data"
```

The 'brien' portion ends up outside of the string value you're comparing to the username field, and causes a parse error. In other words, every single one of your queries is an SQL injection hack waiting to happen.

At utter bare minimum, you need to do something like:

```
$username = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['username']);
```

to make that data "safe" for stuffing into a querys string.

Comment: Have you checked for errors? `mysql_query()` returns boolean FALSE if something blows up. `$stmt = mysql_query(...) or die(mysql_error())` should be in place on every single query call.

Comment: I've added or dir(mysql_error()) after every query call. And still nothing. I save the file and refresh the page and try to sign up again. I still get a blank page. I'm new to all this web designing so I might be missing something. Please help.

Comment: Turn on PHP errors. You're probably in a "production" type environment which hides all error messages. Particularly the php.ini `display_errors` and `display_startup_errors`, and set `error_reporting` to `E_ALL`. And perhaps as well set the `error_log` to a file you have access to, so errors get logged there as well.

Answer (score 0):

the hint is in the line

> Access denied for user
>   'www-data'@'localhost'

it looks like your access to the mysql database is being done as the www user and not the user samaniac

can you try the following on your page somewhere

```
$link = mysql_connect('localhost', 'samaniac', 'your password here');
if (!$link) {
    die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
}
echo 'Connected successfully';
mysql_close($link);
```

and tell me what you get...

Answer (score -1):

OK, I've edited the registration.php code. Have a look at it. I got an error: Access denied for user 'www-data'@'localhost' (using password: NO). I guess that means it's not recognizing my sql username/password or something of the sort. Anyhow, here's my php file:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en" id="jmtoday" class=" no_js">
<head>
<link href='icon.jpg' rel='icon' type='image/jpg'/>
<meta http-equiv="Content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<meta http-equiv="Content-language" content="en" />
<LINK REL=StyleSheet HREF="Mainstyles.css" TYPE="text/css"></link>
<Title>Sign up to JM Today</title>
</head>
<body>
<?php 
    $dbservertype='mysql';
    $servername='localhost';
    $dbusername='samaniac';
    $dbpassword='*****';
    $dbname='jmtdy';
    function connecttodb($servername,$dbname,$dbuser,$dbpassword)
    {
        global $link;
        $link=mysql_connect("$servername","$dbuser","$dbpassword");
        if(!$link){
            die("Could not connect to MySQL");
                }
    connecttodb($servername,$dbname,$dbusername,$dbpassword);           
mysql_select_db("$dbusername",$link) or die ("could not open db".mysql_error());
}
?>


<?php

    $username=mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['username']);
    $password=mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['password']);
    $password2=mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['password_confirmation']);
    $todo=mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['todo']);
    $email=mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['email']);
    $fname=mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['fname']);
    $lname=mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['lname']);



if(isset($todo) and $todo=="post"){

    $status = "OK";
    $msg="";
    }

if(!isset($username) OR strlen($username) <3){
    $msg=$msg."Username should be equal to or more than 3 characters long<BR/>";
    $status= "NOTOK";
    }                   

if(mysql_num_rows(mysql_query("SELECT username FROM users WHERE username = '$username'")or die (mysql_error ()))){
$msg=$msg."Username already exists. Please try another one<BR/>";
$status= "NOTOK";}                  


if ( strlen($password) < 3 ){
    $msg=$msg."Password must be more than 3 charactors long<BR/>";
    $status= "NOTOK";
    }                   

if ( $password <> $password2 ){
    $msg=$msg."Passwords are not identical.<BR/>";
    $status= "NOTOK";
    }                   


if($status<>"OK"){
    echo "$msg<br/><input type='button' value='Retry' onClick='history.go(-1)'>";
}
    else {
if(mysql_query("insert into users(username,password,email,fname,lname) values('$username','$password','$email','$fname','$lname')")or die (mysql_error ())){
    echo "Welcome, You have successfully signed up";
    }
else { 
echo "Database Problem, please contact Site admin";
}

}
?>
</body>
</html>
```